# How to resize image in php as per screen size?

Tags: php, html, css

This type of question is already asked but none is very helpful. Here I am taking an image from database using php and displaying it. I want the image to adjust itself according to screensize and should have max-width limit. How should I do it in php? I tried my best to do it but was unsuccessful.

```
<?php
    $searchword=$_POST['searchword'];
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','bookspyramid');
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<?php
$sql="SELECT imgno FROM bookinfo where bookname='$searchword'";
if($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
  {
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {  
        $imgname=$row['imgno'];
        echo "<img src=imgfile/".$imgname." height= width= >";
      }
  }
}
else
  echo "Sorry! No results found!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Image is showing and has a fixed size, but I want it's dimension to change according to screensize.

Comment: Use relative sizes like 80% or etc use CSS for this purpose to adjust other properties like alignment, position etc. It will adjust image according to size available.

Comment: @ShivCKushawah, I tried using that but not working. It would be greatful if you will give a code snippet for using css in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative sizes like 80% etc through CSS for this purpose.

Also you can adjust other properties like `alignment, position, max-width, max-height` etc. It will adjust image according to size available.

```
<?php
    $searchword=$_POST['searchword'];
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','bookspyramid');
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .myImg {
      max-width:100%;
      width: 80%;
      height: auto; 
      margin: auto auto; /* align center */
   }
</style>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<?php
$sql="SELECT imgno FROM bookinfo where bookname='$searchword'";
if($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
  {
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {  
        $imgname=$row['imgno'];
        echo "<img class='myImg' src='imgfile/".$imgname."'>"; //add '' inside "" around imgfile to avoid img name errors
      }
  }
}
else
  echo "Sorry! No results found!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also use inline CSS for this purpose

```
echo "<img style='width:80%; height: auto; max-width: 100%; margin: auto;' 
 src='imgfile/".$imgname."'>";
```